# $ \sigma(T)$ for operator $T:l_2 \to l_2$

Tags: spectral-theory

Let $(c_n)_n$ a bounded succession of complex numbers, and $T:\ell_2 \to \ell_2$ a operator defined by $T(x)=(c_nx_n)_n$, for all $x = (x_n)_n \in l_2$.

Show that if $\lambda \notin \overline{\{c_n\}}$, then $\lambda \notin \sigma(T)$

I have succeeded in demonstrating that each $(c_n)$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ and considering $\lambda \notin \overline{\{c_n\}}$, $T-\lambda I$ is injective. I would have to prove that it is also surjective, so $\lambda \notin \sigma(T)$, but I can not do it, help please.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $\lambda\notin\overline{\{c_n\}}$, then $\delta:=\inf_n|\lambda-c_n|>0$. If $(\lambda I-T)^{-1}$ existed, what would it be?

Comment: I'm sorry Jason, I do not know how to use the suggestion, could you give me another suggestion?

Comment: To show $A=\lambda I-T$ is invertible, it is sufficient to find a bounded operator $B$ such that $AB=BA=I$. What must this $B$ look like? Once you have determined this, you are left with showing $B$ is bounded, but this is fairly simple given the hint above.